# How to add second WSL2 Ubuntu distro (fresh install)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an existing Ubuntu distro, I want a 2nd one that is a fresh Ubuntu image.

I suspect I can:

1. export my existing distribution to tar with `wsl.exe --export`
2. unregister my existing distro with `wsl unregister`
3. uninstall Ubuntu from Microsoft Store
4. reinstall Ubuntu from Microsoft Store, giving me a fresh install
5. import from tar via `wsl --import`

That should give me 2 distros, my existing plus one fresh. Is there an easier/better way?

This is for latest (as of writing) Windows 10 Build 19035

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Important:** The following procedure works only in [Windows 10 Build 18305](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-18305)
or above. Please make sure `wsl.exe` has `--import` option in commandline.
For older Windows 10 version, try this [alternative method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51691577/8928481).

### Procedure:

- First we need the rootfs tarball from Ubuntu. Open https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/ (for Ubuntu < 22.04) or https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/wsl/ (for Ubuntu >= 22.04)
  in a web browser. Go to the folder with the required Ubuntu version.
- Download the `ubuntu-x.x-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz` file
  (x.x used as version number). Make sure the file name has `amd64-wsl` and the
  file type is `.tar.gz` (GZIP tarball). As example, the direct link will be like this:

```
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/eoan/release/ubuntu-19.10-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz
```

- Now we are going to install it using `wsl.exe` in commandline. Open Command Prompt.
  The actual command format will be like this:

```
wsl.exe --import <Distribution Name> <Install Folder> <.TAR.GZ File Path>
```

- Run the command twice to install Ubuntu with different distribution name.
  The folder name and distribution name **must be different** otherwise there will
  be error shown in output. Here are the two example:

```
wsl.exe --import DistroA FolderA ubuntu-x.x-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz
wsl.exe --import DistroB FolderB ubuntu-x.x-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz
```

- The installed distributions can be executed like this `wsl.exe -d DistroA`.

### Notes:

- The procedure can be used with any GNU/Linux distribution user space.
- This does not use Windows Store. So, Windows Store neither show the name
  nor update the installation.
- In Windows 10 ARM64 (AArch64), use the `arm64-wsl` cloud image for Ubuntu.
- In this procedure the installation folder can be accessed by other users in
  that same machine. If you are using a shared machine, use proper permissions.
- If you are willing to share the installation with other users of same machine
  then just export this registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`.
  Then import it in other users of same machine.

### Further Readings:

- [Command Reference for Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference)

Comment: This will *not* create the non-root user like the distro from the Windows Store does. See my answer for details on creating non-root user: https://superuser.com/a/1531220/714595

Comment: "This will not create the non-root user" -- that depends on the user and it's not the topic of the question.

Comment: Completely agree that it depends on the user, but if the goal is to have multiple distros similar to the one created by the Windows Store, I believe it is useful supplemental information.

Comment: It seems as of now some WSL-specific images are at https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/wsl/. The 22.04 image is about 500 MiB in size, so about 100 MiB bigger than the `ubuntu-x.x-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz` images at https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/. Not sure how they differ...

Answer (score 32):

[Answer by Biswapriyo](https://superuser.com/a/1515275/714595) works great, but additional steps are required to change the default user. Note that this requires [build 18980 and above](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-18980).

Add the non-root user via `adduser` command:

```
PS C:\Users\Username> wsl -d DistroA
root@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/Username# NEW_USER=username
root@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/Username# adduser "${NEW_USER}"
Adding user `username' ...
Adding new group `username' (1000) ...
Adding new user `username' (1000) with group `username' ...
Creating home directory `/home/username' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
New password: ****
Retype new password: ****
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for username
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
        Full Name []: User Name
        Room Number []:
        Work Phone []:
        Home Phone []:
        Other []:
Is the information correct? [Y/n]
```

Enable sudoer privileges for `${NEW_USER}`:

```
adduser ${NEW_USER} sudo
```

Add set the default user in /etc/wsl.conf:

```
tee /etc/wsl.conf <<_EOF
[user]
default=${NEW_USER}
_EOF
```

Exit WSL via `logout`, and then issue the WSL shutdown command for the changes to take effect:

```
wsl --shutdown DistroA
```

The next time `wsl -d DistroA` is invoked, the `${NEW_USER}` user will be active.

Comment: Just a note - `wsl --shutdown` will shutdown all running distros, it doesn't take any arguments. Use `wsl --terminate <distro>` for shutting down a specific distro.

Comment: @TimorGruber, it seemed to work for me.  I created a 2nd 22.04 and called it jammy2.  After running `wsl --shutdown jammy2` I did a `wsl -l -v` and see that the default one Ubuntu is still running while the new jammy2 is not.  Maybe things have changed since January.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same issue, as I am working with different companies at the same time, and needed a script that could easily create a new WSL2 instance, and just as easily delete it.

Deletion by itself is not hard, as the official command `wsl --unregister <distro_name>` works just fine, and gets rid of the WSL2 instances perfectly, without leaving any trace.

Creation however, can be troublesome or even tedious. My script does just this: https://github.com/IAL32/WSL2-Create-Distro

The following example creates a WSL2 instance using Ubuntu20.04 (Focal Fossa) using a previously downloaded
tarball (the example uses the following one: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/current/focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz), creates a user with username `myuser`
and adds it to the group `sudo`. It also sets the user password to the one given in the pipeline, and the password for the root user, also given in the pipeline.

```
.\CreateLinuxDistro.ps1 -INPUT_FILENAME .\focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz -OUTPUT_DIRNAME "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages\ubuntu2004-test-1" -OUTPUT_DISTRONAME ubuntu2004-test-1 -CREATE_USER 1 -CREATE_USER_USERNAME myuser -ADD_USER_TO_GROUP 1 -ADD_USER_TO_GROUP_NAME sudo -SET_USER_AS_DEFAULT myuser
```

Under the hood, if a new user is created it will also change its default shell from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the scripts. It helps a lot. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late, but found your post and tried a different way.

I wanted 2 x a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS image. First one was easy, just the standard one from the Windows store. For the second one I installed an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image for the Windows Store and did an "do-release-upgrade" to upgrade it to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use Ubuntu "base" images instead (less bloated than "cloud" images):

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases - base images
- https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/ - cloud images

You download rootfs and import it:

```
wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/22.04/release/ubuntu-base-22.04-base-amd64.tar.gz
wsl --import my-ubuntu c:\wsl\my-ubuntu ubuntu-base-22.04-base-amd64.tar.gz --version 2
```

**UPDATE** First line of `/etc/passwd` or the user defined in `/etc/wsl.conf` + `passwd` define an app that starts.

To troubleshoot you can specify entry point yourself with `-e`: `wsl -d BaseUbuntu -e /bin/sh`

You can look inside rootfs archive to see which apps are in `/bin` / `/usr/bin`. After finding the shell you can run image as root:

```
wsl -d my-ubuntu -u root -e /bin/sh
```

and update default shell with `chsh` or other available tools.

Comment: how do you launch the base image? using the cloud one I'm able to do `wsl -d NAME` and get a root shell, but with the base image nothing happens (just returns to the windows prompt/powershell)

Comment: @NickSlash See UPDATE

Comment: not sure what I'm doing wrong but I still get nothing (using the same image from your example). The first line of `passwd` is the root user and there is no `wsl.conf`. Looking through `/bin` and `/usr/bin` both sh and bash exist but neither will run.